# MonoDb Cshare Samus Use Collection.Count<T>(func) or shell db.collection.find(condition).count() very slow

Tags: mongodb, count

I am sorry to trouble you about a MongoDb for Cshare driver(Samus) issue,Could you help to give a look.

```
 using (Mongo mongo = new Mongo(config.BuildConfiguration()))
        {
            mongo.Connect();
            try
            {
                var db = mongo.GetDatabase("MyCollection");//Collection 's count > 500,000,000
                var collection = db.GetCollection<BasicData>();
                Console.WriteLine("Count by LINQ on typed collection: {0}", collection.Linq().Count(x => x.Id > 1));////error ,timeout     
                Console.WriteLine("Count by not LINQ on typed collection: {0}", collection.Count());  //no condition is ok                   
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            finally{
                mongo.Disconnect();
            }  }
```

use Mongodb shell:

db.collection.find(condition).count() 
or 
db.collection.count(condition);   //very slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's also slow in the shell then it doesn't have anything to do with the C# driver.

Use [`explain`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain/) to determine whether your query is using the index you expect.  If it's not using an index, any query over 500M docs is going to take some time.  In the shell:

```
db.collection.find(condition).explain();
```

To speed up your query, you'll likely need to add an [index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/) that includes the fields the query `condition` you're using references.

Comment: thanks ,I have create the data index for querying. The memory is 64G in my server,but the query still slowly(only count query slowly,other function query is normal),could you help to find another method to fix this issue?

Comment: What do your documents look like?  What index did you create?  What does `condition` contain?  Did you wait for the index to finish being created?